# Razer Deathstalker keyboard [Fn] (Function) key getting ignored

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, function-keys

Whether I do <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> or just <kbd>F3</kbd>, the OS still just receives a single <kbd>F3</kbd> in both cases.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> should result in increasing the system volume.

None of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd> combos do anything other than sending a <kbd>F#</kbd>.

*Running latest Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1*

Comment: `xev` will show you keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or why it wasn't working but I had it shut down for a day and started it up and the function key is working now. Wish I had an answer as to why it wasn't though.